# Update Table from a Singelton?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I writing a chat app which has several different viewControllers.

Ive implemented a Singelton to listen for new messages from the server. When i receive a new message i want to update the correct TableView within another viewController (`TabFirstViewController`) the table inside that viewController is called `visitorsTableView`.

Here is my current Singleton implementation:

```
#import "ChatDataController.h"
#import "TabFirstViewController.h"

@implementation ChatDataController
{
    ChatDataController * anotherSingles;
}

@synthesize enString;
@synthesize enInt;
@synthesize messages;


+ (ChatDataController *)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static ChatDataController *chatDataController;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ { chatDataController = [[ChatDataController alloc] init];});
    return chatDataController;
}


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

// Open connection to server
- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
    isConnected = TRUE;
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 8080, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

    NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);


    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

            if (theStream == inputStream) {

                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                int len;

                while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if (len > 0) {

                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                        if (nil != output) {

                            NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                            [self messageReceived:output];

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;


        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

            NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
            isConnected = 0;
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:

            [theStream close];
            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            //[theStream release];
            theStream = nil;

            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }

}

// I want to update the table from this method...
- (void) messageReceived:(NSString *)message {

    [self.messages addObject:message];

    /**
    * Trying to update the table..
    */
    TabFirstViewController *controller = [[TabFirstViewController alloc] init];

    NSString *s = (NSString *) [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:messages.count-1 inSection:0];


    NSIndexPath *topIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:messages.count-1
                                                   inSection:0];
    [controller.visitorsTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:topIndexPath
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle
                              animated:YES];

    [controller.visitorsTableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

How should i go about updating my `visitorsTableView` table? I want to keep it updated as i receive new messages from the server.

It should be said that i have more viewControllers each containing a tableView, so i want to be able to update them down the line as well..

Answer (score 0):

You can not initialize Table view every time you receive message.
There are two ways, 
1. Using delegate pattern , 
   Preferred when you need to delegate call to single handler
2. Using Local Notifications
   Preferred when you have multiple handlers to same notification. ( I will recommend this for your chat app )

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Notifications to get you notified when new messages are received. Notification call back can be used to reload your table views.